# Can jQuery / Javascript be viewed within an app?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, arrays, phonegap

I am building an application (via PhoneGap) to be used by IOS and Android users (hopefully).

A main factor of the app involves using jQuery to work out various scenarios based on the data inputted by the user. It is important that the jQuery cannot be accessed / viewed or the idea could be easily copied. Is there a method to protect against this?

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Users will not be able to access you code from their device. Phonecap creates an XCode project in order to make it available to IOS so there is no worry of anyone getting access to your secrets as far as i know.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help :).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code is usually packaged by phonegap/cordova with no protection at all. For instance, you can find it just by unzipping your .apk. The only thing is left to you is to add an obfuscation stage to your packaging pipeline  (e.g., uglify) or hide your sensitive code somewhere else outside the app (e.g., serverside). Only the latter would guarantee the real protection against copy and reverse engineering.